# Print big letter N with #

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm a beginner and I have to print the letter "N" out of #'s.
So far I can only print the |\ , so I'm still missing the last 'leg'.
I don't actually know how I got so far as this.. If anyone can help me or explain!!
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        cout << "#";
        for (j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
        {
            if (i == j)
            {
                cout << "#";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to print a `#` at the end of every line.  If you look at your code you should find where you end lines.  You just need to change that.

Answer (score 5):

```
for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++)  //prints one line at a time
{
    cout << "#";
    for (j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
    {
        if (i == j) cout << "#";  //Diagonal part
        else cout << " ";
    }
    cout << "#";  // <<< You missed this
    cout << endl;
}
```

Little more elegant (using only one `for`-loop):

```
for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
    string s = "#";
    s.append(i-1, ' ' );
    s +='#';
    s.append(9-i, ' ' );
    s +='#';
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i would go for the "Cheeting" way printing the exact thing without mangling with loops.

```
cout << "##      #" << endl
cout << "# #     #" << endl
cout << "#  #    #" << endl
cout << "#   #   #" << endl
cout << "#    #  #" << endl
cout << "#     # #" << endl
cout << "#      ##" << endl
```

easy as pie.

Comment: You made my day

Answer (score -1):

```
    for(int y=0; y<9;y++){

    for(int i=0; i<9; i++){

    if((i==8&&y==0) or(i==8&&y==8) ){std::cout<<" ";}

    if(i==0 or i==8){std::cout<<"#";}else{std::cout<<" ";};

    if(i>0 && i<8){if(i==y){std::cout<<"#";std::cout<<" ";}else{std::cout<<" ";};};

    };std::cout<<"\n";};
```

Comment: perfect diagonal :D